# Problems with send mail using php

Tags: php, email, smtp

Somebody can help me?
I need send email using php.

I am using this code for send mail

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require '/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');
echo (extension_loaded('openssl')?'SSL loaded':'SSL not loaded')."\n"; 

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                   // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = true;                              // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '******';                           // SMTP password


$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = $_POST['email'];
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('email@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     

$mail->IsHTML(false);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$message = $_POST['message'];
$mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mail->Body = preg_replace('/\[\]/','',$message);
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}


?>
```

The return is always this.

```
 SSL loaded 2015-06-02 19:05:41 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2015-06-02 19:09:56   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) 2015-06-02 19:09:56   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I am using PHPMailer. 
I already read https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting, but nothing change.

Comment: Well, this looks like a connection error on network level. Either your script does not have network access at all, or it cannot connect to that specified smtp server. Server and port can be connected to, so it must be a problem on your side.

Comment: Pretty sure smtp.gmail.com requires authentication.

Comment: Also, have you logged into gmail and enabled pop/smtp access on your account?

Comment: how can i make this?